# Constructing IOVector from Storable MVector

Tags: haskell, vector

How do you build [`IOVector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/latest/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable-Mutable.html#t%3aIOVector) from [`MVector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/latest/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable-Mutable.html#t%3aMVector)? `IOVector` is documented as:

```
type IOVector = MVector RealWorld
```

I have a MVector like below, and will like to construct IOVector (for input to MSV.unsafeWith function - MSV is short-hand for Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable library):

```
v <- MSV.replicate 5 0 :: (IO (MVector (PrimState IO) CShort))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type PrimState IO = RealWorld
```

(from the primitive package's [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/primitive/0.4.1/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Primitive.html#line-49))

So an `MVector (PrimState IO)` *is* an `MVector RealWorld` and, thus, an `IOVector`; you can use it directly. `IOVector` is just a convenience synonym so you don't have to type out `MVector RealWorld` all the time :)

Comment: aha, good find. I had quite a headscratcher moment here, trying to figure out what RealWorld type was.